# BBM pin to pin security

Tags: encryption, smartphone

If a BBM message is intercepted over unsecure Wi-Fi and the PIN of the intended recepient is known. Can it be decrypted easily.

Answer (score 2):

BBM messages are encrypted with 3DES, but based on this [CSE page](https://www.cse-cst.gc.ca/en/node/250/html/15202) the key, at least in 2011, was common to all Blackberry devices meaning a device could potentially decrypt a message not destined for it if the device can spoof it's identify.

Apparently Blackberry even mentions that [you should] "consider PIN messages as scrambled, not encrypted".

The answer to your question is still probably No, it would take substantial resources and knowledge to do intercept and decrypt your messages, it wouldn't be 'easy' like cracking a WEP key, but I wouldn't use it for secrecy.